# Highcharts: get index of the selection event

Tags: highcharts

On a chart, it is possible to get the minimum and maximum values when a selection event is performed https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.selection:

```
selection: function(event) {
// log the min and max of the primary, datetime x-axis
console.log(
    Highcharts.dateFormat(
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
        event.xAxis[0].min
    ),
    Highcharts.dateFormat(
        '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
        event.xAxis[0].max
    )
);
// log the min and max of the y axis
console.log(event.yAxis[0].min, event.yAxis[0].max);
```

}

I read that is possible to get the index on a specific selected point. So, I would like to know if it is possible to get also the indexes of those values? because, I want to avoid to search for those values in the series.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid not - the selection event returns only `xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax` coordinates. You need to find points that are included in this range, just like here: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-selection-points/